# SSH connect to remote on local network

Tags: linux, ssh, tunneling

I have 2 computers on linux (ubuntu like), both are on separated local networks (192.168.xxx.xxx).

I would like to connect through ssh to Linux2 from Linux1 but it doesn't have any public IP.

I have also a public server (srv.domain.com)
I suppose that both PC could connect to server and it would be able to forward commands ??

But I can't figure out how to do that. Is someone already did something similar and can explain it to me.

I have root access on all machines

Thanks a lot for your help !!!

Comment: Your question isn't about programming, so it's off-topic for StackOverflow. Nevertheless, [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46271/13377) might help shed some light on how tunnels work, and where you connect what to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make the firewall/router allow ssh connections between the hosts. But there is another way:

If your server can reach both clients, you can ssh onto the server and redirect a port to the ssh on the other machine:

```
ssh -L 1234:CLIENT2:22 -l USERNAME SERVERNAME
```

after logging into the the machine open another terminal window and enter:

```
ssh -l USERNAME -p 1234 localhost
```

- USERNAME should be replaced with the username on the server/second
  client.
- CLIENT2 should be replaced by the ip or hostname of the
  second client.
- SERVERNAME should be replaces by the name of your
  server.

---

You can also ssh onto the server and open another ssh session from there. But that would be to easy ;)

---

If your server cannot reach the clients you have to build the tunnel the other way round:

```
ssh -R 1234:22 -l USERNAME SERVERNAME
```

after logging into the the machine open a terminal window on the other machine and enter:

```
ssh -l USERNAME -p 1234 SERVERNAME
```

- USERNAME should be replaced with the username on the server/second
  client.
- SERVERNAME should be replaces by the name of your
  server.